# Checking if 2 lines of text are nearly equal in R

Tags: string, r, matching, text-processing

I have the below data, where I want to check if any 2 records have the same address.

```
Id  Class   Address
42  18  PLOT#39 H#8-2-293/A4/A/
42  68  PLOT #39 H #8-2-293/A4/A
42  35  PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO
42  34  PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO
42  00  PLOT 1030 BUNGLOW NO 3
42  53  PLOT NO-39 H#8-2-293/A4/
42  70  GAYATRAI RESIDENCY MADHU
```

I am tokenizing Address using **strsplit(dt$Address, " ")** and storing it in a list variable. I will consider it as the same address if 70% of the words match.

My problem here is when I use strplit(), it gives me a

```
> strsplit(dt$Address, " ")[1]
[[1]]
[1] "PLOT#39"  "H#8-2-293/A4/A/"
```

So here I am not able to iterate over the words to check if these words are present in the other Address list. How can I check if they are nearly equal addresses.

Comment: GLWT :-( . The USPS and literally hundreds of mail-order companies have tried to obtain software which does that correctly.  Matching exact strings is easy;  figuring out which strings correspond to the same actual address is a nightmare.

Comment: `strsplit` returns a list, so use `lapply` to loop over it. Overwise, you might want to consider using `agrep` for fuzzy string matching.

Comment: Also use double square brackets to extract list elements, eg `strsplit(dt$Address, " ")[[1]]`

Comment: agrep looks interesting. I am going to try around that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tokenize it based on more than just space. Try adding the `#` and/or `/` to receive a "better" list of words.

```
> strsplit("PLOT#39 H#8-2-293/A4/A/", " |#")[1]
[[1]]
[1] "PLOT"          "39"            "H"             "8-2-293/A4/A/"

> strsplit("PLOT#39 H#8-2-293/A4/A/", " |#|/")[1]
[[1]]
[1] "PLOT"    "39"      "H"       "8-2-293" "A4"      "A"
```

How you continue from here is a tough one tho - you can check how many parts match with others or some other algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the `stringdist` package which implements a large number of different string distance measures. For example,

```
data <- "Id,Class,Address
42,18,PLOT#39 H#8-2-293/A4/A/
42,68,PLOT #39 H #8-2-293/A4/A
42,35,PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO
42,34,PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO
42,00,PLOT 1030 BUNGLOW NO 3
42,53,PLOT NO-39 H#8-2-293/A4/
42,70,GAYATRAI RESIDENCY MADHU"
data <- read.csv(textConnection(data), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

# Create a data.frame with all combinations of addresses
d2 <- expand.grid(data$Address, data$Address)
# remove duplicate addresses
d2 <- d2[d2[[1]] != d2[[2]], ]

# calculate distance
library(stringdist)
d2$d <- stringdist(d2[[1]], d2[[2]], method="jw")
```

There are a large number of string distance measures. I have used the Jaro-Winkler distance (which is often used for comparing names), but you'll have to try to see which one works best for you. You can then select the addresses which are most similar:

```
> # show records with a distance smaller than 0.15
> d2[d2$d < 0.15, ]
                       Var1                     Var2          d
2  PLOT #39 H #8-2-293/A4/A  PLOT#39 H#8-2-293/A4/A/ 0.05742205
8   PLOT#39 H#8-2-293/A4/A/ PLOT #39 H #8-2-293/A4/A 0.05742205
19   PLOT 1030 BUNGLOW NO 3  PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO 0.13937512
26   PLOT 1030 BUNGLOW NO 3  PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO 0.13937512
31  PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO   PLOT 1030 BUNGLOW NO 3 0.13937512
32  PLOT NO 1030 BUNGLOW NO   PLOT 1030 BUNGLOW NO 3 0.13937512
```

However, depending on how varied your addresses are you might have to standardise the addresses first. I don't know of an R package that does that. I know that [Febrl](http://datamining.anu.edu.au/projects/linkage.html#prototype_software) should have some tools for address standardisation, but I have never used them so can't comment on their usability.